# Difference between find -name with and w/o quotes?

Tags: linux, find, gnu

I was going to file a bug to findutils on gnu.org when I saw a notice that asked me whether I knew the difference between these two commands:

```
find -name *.c
```

and

```
find -name "*.c"
```

I use find command quite often but I don't think these two have any difference. So I'm curious am I wrong or it's just another GNU guys kidding?

Comment: Try the same in [Fish](http://fishshell.com/), and it will teach you a lesson – you have been a bad boy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first example, your shell will first expand the `*.c` to match all files in the current directory which end in `.c`.

So, if you have `one.c`, `zwei.c`, and `tres.c` in your directory, your shell will expand this to

```
find . -name one.c zwei.c tres.c
```

and `find` will probably get confused because you're passing a couple extra arguments after `-name one.c` -- `zwei.c` and `tres.c` are not considered part of what you're searching with `-name`.

In the second example, you're passing the literal string `*.c` to the `-name` option of `find`. This is something that `find` knows how to deal with -- and probably what you're looking for.

An alternate way to accomplish the same thing would be with a backslash escape:

```
find . -name \*.c
```

(Note also that your examples need an argument to tell `find` where to start the search. This is often just `.` to indicate the current directory.)

Comment: GNU `find` defaults to `.` as the search path.

Comment: I did not know that. Another case of me using a tool for so long that I'm not caught up on modern conveniences.

Comment: Trye. The GNU version defaults to that. Still, it is a good case to explicitly write the dot. Both for making the code more understandable and for compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

The former will only result in `*.c` if you have no files that match that in the current directory, otherwise it will expand to those filenames. The latter will always result in the text `*.c`.

Comment: bash has an option for what it does if `*.c` does not match. It could evaluate to `*.c` or nothing (or maybe something else, I can't remember).

Comment: Try `shopt -s failglob` or `shopt -s nullglob` for safer behaviour.